# Как добиться pixel perfect при верстке Android-приложения?

Tags: android, вёрстка, мобильные-приложения

Передаю разработчику макеты в фигме. Там есть режим инспектора, в котором видны все расстояния и стили.
Но результат не радует. Отступы скачут, стили тоже. Приложение смотрится как черновик, который забыли доработать.

Вопрос в том, существует ли какой то флоу или инструмент для того, чтобы верстка приложения соответствовала макетам?

Comment: инструмент?.. целых два: глаза и руки

Comment: Что-то суть проблемы непонятна. Если отступы неправильные - нужно просто взять и прописать правильные, не?

Comment: Дайте разработчику два слова Constraint Layout.

Answer (score 0):

Здесь нужно понимать наверное 2 вещи:

- Первая - это то насколько грамотно сделан дизайн. Т.е. нужно понимать, что в Android есть огромное количество устройств, которые имеют разные размеры экранов, разные соотношения сторон.

  Поэтому важно верстать экран не в жестко заданных пикселях, а в соотношении UI друг к другу. Т.е. к примеру у вас есть большая кнопка внизу экрана, она не должна быть шириной 290 пикселей (dp), иначе она будет на разных девайсах смотреться по разному. Но она должна иметь к примеру строго 16 пикселей (dp) отступы слева и справа.

  Конечно могут быть элементы и с жестко заданными размерами, но это скорее отдельные исключения.
- Второе - это разработчик. Нет ничего сложного в том, чтоб прописать правильные размеры в вашем UI. И если первое это не про вас, а ваш разработчик не может сверстать правильные размеры - то скорее всего тут не инструмент нужно новый искать, а разработчика.